# DisableCache in web.config not working on GoDaddy

Tags: caching, iis, web-config, plesk, godaddy-api

I recently put a basic site out on GoDaddy, and for obvious reasons, I don't want it caching the HTML files.  JSON files and other resources are fine, but not the initial HTML files themselves.

This site was hand-coded in Notepad++; WordPress was not used.

On my local IIS server, the caching for HTML files was disabled without much trouble.  This is the web.config file for the overall site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
                <remove value="index.htm" />
                <remove value="Default.asp" />
                <remove value="Default.htm" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <caching>
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".html" policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The `add`element under `caching/profiles` works just fine on my IIS server when testing locally.  However it's been noticed that it is effectively getting ignored on GoDaddy / Plesk.

So my question is: What do you have to do to get GoDaddy / Plesk to go ahead and stop caching the HTML files?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below code in your web.config file:

```
 <caching>
      <add extension=".html" policy="DontCache" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />
   </caching>
```

when you try to access site hard refresh the browser and check that is it working or not.

You could refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/caching/profiles/add) for more detail.